# SSLConnectionSocketFactory error in JMeter and WebDriver Set

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I've encountered problems with starting JMeter and WebDriver Set.

I set - Thread Group with:

jp@gc FF Driver Config

jp@gc Web Driver Sampler

View Results in Table

In Web Driver Sampler I have following lines:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

And I get following error:

> ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you use the [latest JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) version (2.13 as for the moment)
2. Make sure you use the latest [WebDriver Set plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSet/) package (1.3.1 as for now)
3. Make sure you use supported Firefox version

   > Supports native events for Firefox version 31 (immediately previous ESR).
   >   Native event support has been discontinued for versions of Firefox later
   >   than 33. Synthetic events tested on Firefox versions 31 (immediately
   >   previous ESR), 38 (immediately previous release and current ESR), and 39
   >   (current release).
4. Before starting JMeter:

   - go to JMeter's /lib folder
   - locate .jar files which names start with "http"
   - delete files which have lesser versions
5. If you still experience problems check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide